# How to implement caching for tokens in Django Rest Framework and Firebase Auth

Tags: django, firebase, caching, django-rest-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm building an API using Django Rest Framework and I was thinking about using Firebase for authentication. I have some questions about how to implement the caching layer.

**This is how the application works: **
A user logs in using the frontend (React.js), then when I make an API call to DRF and I pass the auth token sent back by Firebase. Using that token, DRF calls Firebase again to retrieve the user, and finally I retrieve the UserProfile for that user in DRF by querying a Postgres db.

I want all this operations to result in the least amount of calls to Firebase, hence I was thinking about caching the (user token, user id) pair. However, I have never implemented caching in Django before and would appreciate any guidance. Also, what caching strategy and tool can you recommend me? Thank you

Comment: Don't cache Firebase user id tokens.  They expire after an hour and should be sent with every request from the client. The client app should make sure it is sending an unexpired token every time.

Comment: @DougStevenson In that case it, doesn't make sense to do caching on the id tokens. Can you recommend me any way of lowering my costs if I were to still use Firebase for Authentication? Is there any place that I can do caching at all that is related to this. Thank so much for taking the time to help me with this question.

Comment: What cost are you trying to reduce, exactly?  There is miniscule cost to send a token in each request, and none to use Firebase Auth in general.  If you have a new question, please post it separately, and show the code that isn't working the way you expect.